# Determine needed class dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

I have several external devices which I can communicate to via a common API.

```
string busIdentifier = "BUS:0:1";
var dev = new CommonDeviceDriver(busIdentifier);
```

Now I can query the device:

```
string identifier = dev.QueryIdentifier();
```

Now I have several concrete driver for example `ConcreteDeviceA`, `ConcreteDeviceB` and `ConcreteDeviceC`. Each of the device driver should have an ìdentifier`.

Now I want to load the right device driver for this previously queried identifer.

How to to that in `C#`?

Coming from  `python` I would do something like that:

```
# Have a dictionary where key is identifier and value is the class
supported_devices = {ConcreteDeviceA.identifer : ConcreteDeviceA,
                     ConcreteDeviceB.identifer : ConcreteDeviceB,
                     ConcreteDeviceC.identifer : ConcreteDeviceC}
busIdentifier = "BUS:0:1"
dev = CommonDeviceDriver(busIdentifier)
identifier = dev.QueryIdentifier()
concrete_device = supported_devices[identifier](dev) # Get class and call constructor
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The Dictionary part? What have you tried in C#?

Comment: Well there are a few ;). In this `python` example all Concrete devices implement an interface to guarantee they have the static member ìdentifier` --> `static properties` are not possible with an Interface. How to design such a behavior in C#?

Comment: Well, I see what you want... In C#, when you want to add "identification" to a class, you can't do it by using static property. However, what you can do is add `Attribute` to the class which can store data specific to that class.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be a [factory method](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethodPattern).  If you know the available types at compile-time, then you can simply enumerate them in code.

```
public static DriverBase CreateDriver(string identifier, object device) {
    switch (identifier) {
    case IDENTIFIER_A: return new ConcreteDeviceA(device);
    // etc
    }
}
```

If you don't know all of the types at compile time (or you really object to the above usage), then you can use reflection.  Then you can essentially have a dictionary mapping identifier to type (as you have in Python), and instantiate the object either using `Activator.CreateInstance`, or by looking up its constructor yourself.  In that case, you'll have to cast the return object to the base type.